# ThreadPoolExecutor rejected error

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the meaning of following error? How I can recover it?

```
Exception in thread "UserActionProcessor-8811" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@56624074 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5fd03556[Running, pool size = 300, active threads = 300, queued tasks = 2000, completed tasks = 7979]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means the thread pool is busy and queue is full as well. The task is then rejected. I think you should implement rejection policy if you don't want any task to be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

You exceeded the maximum number of tasks running in parallel (300) and the maximum number of tasks waiting to start execution (2000). Your execution service can't handle that much tasks or submitted tasks is too time consuming.