# how to solve the bug in picture download thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, download, threadpool

In my code,first I access an address and I got the text file. In that, there are many picture links, such as http://dnight-math.stor.sinaapp.com/%E5%9C%B0%E7%90%861_img004.jpg. I use regular expression to find all the links to make a arraylist. Then I use downloadService to download all the pictures.  When I first press a button to download ,it can run successfully. But it doesn't work if the button is pressed again and throws error. I think this bug is about thread but I don't know how to solve it.

```
HttpUtil.sendHttpRequest(address,
                        new HttpCallbackListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFinish(String response) {

        try {
            ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http:.*?.com/(.*?.(jpg|png))");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(response);
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (m.find()) {
                m.appendReplacement(buffer, "<T>" +                                                 + m.group(1) + "</T>");
                urlList.add(m.group());

            }
            m.appendTail(buffer);
            response = buffer.toString();
            Message m2 = Message.obtain();
            m2.obj = response;
            m2.what = 1;
            mHandler.sendMessage(m2);
            new DownloadService("/data/data/com.baodian/files",
                                urlList,
                                new DownloadStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {                                                    
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed() {
            }
        }, context).startDownload();
        ;

    // JSONObject singleChoice=all.getjson
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
}
});

public class HttpUtil {

    public static void sendHttpRequest(final String address,
        final HttpCallbackListener listener) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection connection=null;
            try {
                URL url=new URL(address);
                connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(8000);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                InputStream in=connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"gbk"));
                StringBuilder response=new StringBuilder();
                String line=null;
                while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                if (listener!=null) {
                    listener.onFinish(response.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onError(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

[image: catlog]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the logcat message?

Comment: @ajantha i have upload all code in picture

Answer (score 0):

If you look at SimY4's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470218/threadpoolexecutor-rejected-error), 
he says that the error you're getting "means the thread pool is busy and queue is full as well".
What you currently do is call `onFailed` when you encounter the error. What you can do is implement
a supplementary enqueing scheme. You can cache the newer urls until the thread queue has space, create and enqueue
the new threads at that point.

The following thread might prove useful : [Java executors: how to be notified, without blocking, when a task completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes)